# Input control in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function verif(){
    var nomR=document.forms["login-form"]["nomR"].value;
    var prenomR=document.forms["login-form"]["prenomR"].value;
    var mail=document.forms["login-form"]["mail"].value;
    var Cmail=document.forms["login-form"]["Cmail"].value;
    var password=document.forms["login-form"]["password"].value;

    var errorN = document.getElementById('errorNR');
    var errorP = document.getElementById('errorPR');
    var errorEmail = document.getElementById('errorMR');
    var errorPass = document.getElementById('errorPass');

    var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

    if (nomR == "") {
        errorN.innerHTML = "Veuillez entrer votre nom!";

    }else if (!(nomR.match(letters) && nomR.charAt(0).match(/^[A-Z]+$/))) {
        errorN.innerHTML = "Veuillez entrer un nom valid!";
    } else {
        errorN.innerHTML = "";

    }
    if (prenomR == "") {
        errorP.innerHTML = "Veuillez entrer votre prenom!";

    }
    else if (!(prenomR.match(letters) && prenomR.charAt(0).match(/^[A-Z]+$/))) {
        errorP.innerHTML = "Veuillez entrer un prenom valid!";
    }
    else {
        errorP.innerHTML = "";

    }
    if (mail == "") {
        errorEmail.innerHTML = "Veuillez entrer votre email!";

    }
    else {
        errorEmail.innerHTML = "";

    }
    if (password == "") {
        errorPass.innerHTML = "Veuillez entrer votre mot de passe!";

    }
    else if (!(password.match(/[0-9]/g) &&
        password.match(/[A-Z]/g) &&
        password.match(/[a-z]/g) &&
        password.length >= 8)) {
        errorPass.innerHTML = "Le mot de passe doit contenir au moins 8 caractères, dont au moins : Une lettre majuscule, Une lettre minuscule et un nombre.";

    }
    else {
        errorPass.innerHTML = "";

    }
}
    function VerifEmail() {
        var mail = document.forms["login-form"]["mail"].value;
        var Cmail = document.forms["login-form"]["Cmail"].value;
        var errorCR = document.getElementById('errorCR');
    
        if (Cmail == "") {
            errorCR.innerHTML = "Veuillez confirmer votre email!";
        }
        if (!(mail == Cmail)) {
            errorCR.innerHTML = "Les deux mails ne sont pas identiques!";
    
        } else {
            errorCR.innerHTML = ""
        }

    

}
function validateForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    verif();
}
```

```css
.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.form button {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background:#000000;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form button:hover,.form button:active,.form button:focus {
  background:#000000;
}
.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.form .message a {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.form .register-form {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-page">
<div class="form">
    <form class="login-form" onsubmit="validateForm(event)" method="post" >
<input type="text" name="nomR" placeholder="first name"/>
<p id="errorNR" class="error"></p>
<input type="text" name="prenomR" placeholder="second name"/>
<p id="errorPR" class="error"></p>
<input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="email address"/>
<p id="errorMR" class="error"></p>
<input type="email" name="cmail" placeholder="confirm email address"/>
<p id="errorCR" class="error" onblur="VerifEmail()" onkeyup="VerifEmail()"></p>
<input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
<p id="errorPass" class="error"></p>
<input type="text" placeholder="Addresse"/>
<input type="tel" placeholder="Phone"/>
<input type="date" placeholder="Birth Date"/>


<input type="submit" value="Envoyer">
<div>
<p class="message">Already registered? <a href="login.html">Sign In</a></p>
</div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

So basicaly i m new to web dev i was working on a registration form and i ran into an issue with input control with javascript and i can t figure out what it is or how to make it work
here is my html and css code and here is my try with java script.
I m trying to print a message if the name is not starting with caps or if the email confirmation is not matching the first email and stuff like that .
i realy appreciate your help

Comment: Have a close look at the errors which you will see in your browser's dev tools inspect facility console. For exampe: although you are using Javascript you have some syntax which looks as though it comes from another language: e.g. document.forms["login-form"]["nomR"] Learning about querySelector and querySelectorAll and what they actually give you is probably the place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems the first one is to check if the name is in **'CAPITAL LETTERS'** or not. For that you can use following code.

```js
const name = document.querySelector(".name");
const errorMessage = name.nextElementSibling; 
// will select the next element of input i.e. <p> with class .error-message

name.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
  if (!isUpperCase(event.target.value)) {
    errorMessage.innerText = 'Please type in "UPPERCASE LETTERS"';
  } else {
    errorMessage.innerText = '';
  }
});

// FUNCTION
const isUpperCase = (str) => str == str.toUpperCase();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="name" required />
<p class="error-message"></p>
```

So, basically what I did was created an `function` which checks the nature of string that means if a string is **UPPERCASE** or not. If the string is in **UPPERCASE** format the function will return `true` otherwise `false`.

Then I used that `true` || `false` value for validation.

---

Now, the second problem is to check the similarity of `email`. Let's say `email` should be equal to `confirm email`. For that use following code

```js
const email = document.querySelector(".email");
const email1 = email.nextElementSibling;
const errorMessage = email1.nextElementSibling;

email1.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
  if (event.target.value.trim() !== email.value.trim()) {
    errorMessage.innerText = 'The two emails are not same';
  } else {
    errorMessage.innerText = '';
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" class="email" required />
<input type="email" class="email1" required />
<p class="error-message"></p>
```

In this I added `EventListener` in the second email field because we need to match the first with the second one. So, the user will type his/her email then jumps for confirmation than as soon as user starts typing we will start to validate. If the email will get matched all good. But if don't we will display an error message.

**P.S** I ignored the styling do it on your own.